# Ways to serialize rust-protobuf messages in Rust

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I am new to Rust and I wonder how should I serialize protobuf messages derived from the `rust-protobuf` lib. What are my options? As I see there is the `protobuf` lib but I have not found options for serialization (I found only deserialization). As I see, other options are `serde` and `bytes`. Which one should I look into? I am looking for serializing for the purpose of sending data between two computers as fast as possible so I am looking into binary, not json.

Comment: Did you check the [FAQ](https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf/blob/master/FAQ.md)?

Comment: Do you have a small code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @HHK. The compiler doesn't find the .write_to_bytes() method on my message. I will post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (https://github.com/stepancheg/rust-protobuf/blob/master/FAQ.md) says:

> The easiest way to do it is to invoke `write_to_bytes` function:
>
> ```
> message.write_to_bytes()
> ```

But I guess by this they mean that message is a type as I don't get this option on message instances.

This works instead:

```
protobuf::Message::write_to_bytes(message)
```

Comment: `message.write_to_bytes()` will work if the `protobuf::Message` trait is in scope